# Can't connect to docker from Docker Go Client in windows 11 with wsl2

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

I want to build an image using the docker go client but can't seem to get it to work

Here is a go function to retrieve the client

```
func getClient() *client.Client {

    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting client: %v", err))
    }
    // fmt.Println("Docker client secured ...")
    return cli
}
```

This the part of function I use to run the build that throws the error. First I get the client form the above shown function, define the context and the build options. After i use the client to run the build `cli.ImageBuild`

```
// ...
       cli := getClient()
       ctx := context.Background()

    buildOptions := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Dockerfile: filepath.Join(directory, "Dockerfile"),
        Tags:       []string{imageName},
    }

    // fmt.Println(filepath.Join(directory, "Dockerfile"))

    buildContext, err := os.Open(directory)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening build context:", err)
        return "", err
    }
    defer buildContext.Close()

    buildResponse, err := cli.ImageBuild(ctx, buildContext, buildOptions)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error building image:", err)
        return "", err
    }
    defer buildResponse.Body.Close()
// ...
```

The error thrown is as follows

```
failed to build docker image: error during connect: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.43/build?buildargs=null&cachefrom=null&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=clonedRepo%5CDockerfile&labels=null&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=&rm=0&shmsize=0&t=jackkweyunga&target=&ulimits=null&version=": read ./clonedRepo: Incorrect function.
```

I was trying to build a docker image using the docker go client